# Scp on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I'm running 18.04 Ubuntu Server.
I'm trying to copy file from my Ubuntu server to my Windows PC.

I have done some of the ssh configurations:

1. install Openssh server on my Windows10 PC and it's enabled
2. edit ssh configuration file

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
3. enable ssh on my Ubuntu Server
   [image]
4. I can ssh server
   [image]
5. I have also configured firewall with following commands:

   ```
   sudo ufw default incoming
   sudo ufw default outgoing
   sudo ufw allow ssh
   sudo ufw allow 22
   sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
   sudo ufw enable
   sudo ufw allow from any to any port 22 proto tcp
   ```

My problem:
I still cannot transfer the file from Ubuntu to Windows.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like more of a Windows problem than an Ubuntu problem ... 

Comment: I think you need to determine if the issue is with the Ubuntu system or the Windows system.  If you have other (working) Ubuntu or Windows to test with, that would be easier.  But playing with the firewall on the Ubuntu system won't help (unless you've somehow blocked all outgoing traffic...), if the issue is with Windows blocking incoming traffic.

Comment: I cannot ping from my Ubuntu server to my Windows10, but I can ping from my Windows10 to my Ubuntu Server. Will this be the problem?

Comment: If you can connect via SSH to the server, why not just use Putty or FileZilla or something on Windows to transfer files from the server? Why set up SSH on Windows?

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Try the -v (verbose) option for scp. This will give you a trace of the authentication/transfer process and so point to where the communication is failing.